# Byobu odd corruption in status bar

Tags: byobu

Anyone seen this before?  Know how I get rid of it?

[image]

The bit between the **18.04** and the **0:-**.  Looks like it reads `|l|_1-30952`, no clue what it is.  If I exit byobu and restart it, it goes away.  It also only looks like it shows up after a detach & re-attach on another computer.  But I can't narrow it down yet.

### Edit

Looks like it's related to the tmux session, as that is the PID of the underlying tmux process.  Still digging.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?